# Database connection msql not configured

Tags: laravel, heroku

I am trying to get laravel up on heroku but i get this error:

> In DatabaseManager.php line 152: Database connection [msql] not
> configured.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you misspelled please correct `DB_CONNECTION` variable from "msql" to "mysql"